# How can I get Firefox to automatically play an .mp3 file?

Tags: firefox, automation

I have Firefox set up to "always do this" with `.mp3s`

I have it set to use Media Player Classic

However, every time I download an .mp3, firefox shows a screen which has *"play it with MPC"* selected as the choice but wants another click to make sure. I'd like to bypass that click.

I can always "right click" to "Save as...", but I would prefer to do this.

Comment: Which version of Firefox are you using? I'm on 3.5.5 here, and it just works. Does the opening dialog have a checkbox in the bottom part, saying "Always do this from now on", or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [OpenDownload add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/207):

> Allows you to open any file from the
>   internet into the OS assigned program.
>   This is similar to IE's 'Open' or
>   'Run' file download functionality.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not working, John.
I still have to click "OK" to complete the demand.

Comment: That's weird. What version of FF are you using?

Comment: 3.5.5    
I use MS for one of my accts and my voip provider sends me emails there with my messages. I'd just like to open them automatically when I click ion them.

Answer (score 1):

Xavierjazz, you didn't mention anything about the "Do this automatically for files like this from now on" check box. Is it there? Is it greyed out? Is it enabled, but seems to have no effect on subsequent downloads?

I suspect that [this](http://kb.mozillazine.org/File_types_and_download_actions#Unable_to_set_an_automatic_action) is the problem you're having; the easiest way to check is by looking at the HTTP headers (with [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843), or [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829), for example) while requesting the .mp3 files.

If your server is actually sending the file with the HTTP header "Content-Disposition: attachment" then I think you're out of luck - unless you're prepared to configure a local proxy, like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), in order to replace that header whenever it comes from your VOIP provider site.

Comment: +1. Thanks.
I thought I was clear, even though I didn't use the exact terminology. That box is checked.

I will look into this more deeply, but this is definitely a great starting point.